# Tensorflow .so issues Mac OS X

Tags: macos, tensorflow, python-3.5, .so

I am having trouble getting the Tensorflow example to progress beyond the first line of code beyond my imports.  With no other errors, I receive the following:

```
NotFoundError: dlopen(/Users/opusandcaymus/Election/word2vec_ops.so, 6): image not found
```

I have a dedicated Tensorflow environment in Anaconda 4.0.1 running Python 3.5.  Tensorflow was freshly installed in that environment as version 1.4.1.  I'm not sure what the .os file does for word2vec, but Google's example problem requires this line ([Google Example Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/code/tensorflow_models/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py)).  Thanks in advance.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys
import threading
import time

from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

word2vec = tf.load_op_library(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__")), 'word2vec_ops.so'))
```